# preg_replace - random word in array

Tags: php, regex, templates, preg-replace

I have the following Code.

```
<?php
$user['username'] = 'Bastian';

$template = 'Hello {user:username}';
$template = preg_replace('/\{user\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/', $user['\1'], $template);
echo $template;

// Output: 
// Notice: Undefined index: \1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 5
// Hello
```

I think, you know what i would do (i hope you know).
I try to replace $user['$1'], $user["$1"] or $user[$1], Nothing Works!

I hope you can help my =)
Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) - the replacement of `preg_replace()` is a string so you cannot use PHP code there. And no, the `/e` modifier is not a solution since eval is evil.

Here's an example (it requires PHP 5.3 but you should be using a recent version anyway!):

```
$user['username'] = 'FooBar';
$template = 'Hello {user:username}';
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{user\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/', function($m) use ($user) {
    return $user[$m[1]];
}, $template);
```

If you **have** to use an old PHP version, you could do it like this. It's much uglier due to the use of a global variable though:

```
function replace_user($m) {
    global $user;
    return $user[$m[1]];
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/\{user\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/', 'replace_user', $template);
```

---

However, **consider using a template engine** such as [**h2o**](http://www.h2o-template.org/) instead of implementing it on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much ^^
<?php
$user['userID'] = '1';
$user['username'] = 'FooBar';

function repl($m)
{
 global $user;
 return $user[$m[1]];
}

$template = 'Hello <a href="index.php?userID={user:userID}">{user:username}</a>';

echo preg_replace_callback('/\{user\:([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\}/', 'repl', $template);

// Output: 
// Hello <a href="index.php?userID=1">FooBar</a></code>